# How do you utilize proxy support with the python aiohttp framework

Tags: python, proxy, aiohttp

Does `os.environ['http_proxy']` still work? 
And how to utilize proxy per request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Proxy support has added to aiohttp in the recent 0.7.3 release.
It doesn't use `os.environ['http_proxy']` and probably will never do.

To specify proxy for request you can use code like this:

```
connector = aiohttp.ProxyConnector(proxies={'http': 'http://proxyaddr:8118'})
response = yield from aiohttp.request('get', 'http://python.org/', connector=connector)
```

HTTPS proxies are not supported yet, sorry.

Perhaps we add the feature very soon: we need for HTTPS proxies for our business tasks.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I saw the update of aiohttp from github yesterday, a bit late to update this question. Thank you again for the great work!